# Add chart to excel with data from multiple sheets using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, charts

I have 60+ sheets with same columns (Time,Data1,Data2,Data3)across all the sheets. I would like to plot a xy scatter smooth line plot of time from all sheets vs the other columns with data from all the sheets in a single plot. What is the most efficient way to do it?
I tried

```
xl=pd.ExcelFile(f_o)
xl_sheets = []
for sheet in xl.sheet_names:
    xl_sheets.append(xl.parse(sheet))
    dfc = pd.concat(xl_sheets)
print dfc.shape
time_df=dfc['UTCTime']
for i in list(dfc.columns):
    print i
    time.sleep(5000)
    if i!='UTCTime':
        ydata=dfc[i]
        print ydata.head()
        xlf.plot(time_df,ydata)     
    else:
        continue    
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I will do with my favorite tools.

## import

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

## Grab data

### For several files

```py
all_df = []
for excel in Path("path/to/files").iterdir():
    all_df.append(pd.read_excel(excel))
df = pd.concat(all_df)
```

### For several sheets in one file

```py
df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", sheet_name=None)
```

## Graph data

```py
for column in df.columns:
    if column != "Time" :
        df.plot.scatter(x="Time", y=column)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I strip a column from the columns list as I don't want to plot time against time?

Comment: @Sridutt I have updated the code. You can also do, df.columns[1:]

Comment: I got error saying scatter plot x-axis takes only numeric values.. Time is a datetime64[ns]

Comment: Any ideas? Thanks so far

Comment: I just used the matplotlib default plot
for {plt.plot("Time",column)}
plt.show
It worked with datetime data as x-axis

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18755
This seems to be an issue in pandas plot as this discussion says.. Interesting that default matplotlib plot is ok with datetime, while pandas built on it has a limitation